# Is there a way to override a git author's display name in local repository config?

Tags: git, configuration

I have a git repository imported from subversion where users have names like `H1234567`. When I run `git log` or `git blame` I'd prefer to see `dave` than `H1234567`.

Can a specific author's name be overridden in config so that all git tools will display the custom name? Alternatively perhaps there is a way to achieve this with gettext? Ideas welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a mailmap file, which can translate authors' name and email without modifying history.

Create a file `.mailmap` at the repository root with the following:

```
dave <dave@example.com>    H1234567 <H1234567@original.com>
```

You can set different email address, or keep the original one.

See [Documentation/mailmap.txt](https://raw.github.com/gitster/git/829a1c616967176ccd859c18a6e8ca0dda77f75a/Documentation/mailmap.txt) for more.