# Incorrect Git user name and email on Windows

Tags: windows, git

I use Git on Windows and set the username and email with:

```
git config --global user.name "hydRAnger"
git config --global user.email "armyiljfe@gmail.com"
```

When I use:

```
git config --global --list
```

I get the output:

> user.name=hydRAnger
>   user.email=armyiljfe@gmail.com

However, when I use `git log` the author info should be:

> Author: hydRAnger `<armyiljfe@gmail.com>`

But in fact I get the output:

> Author: unknown `<hydRAnger@hydRAnger-PC.(none)>`

I don't know why the author information incorect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the `user.name` and `user.email` config options does not change already existing commits. It will only work for future commits.

If you also want to rewrite existing commits to use the new user data check out this question:

[Change the author and committer name and e-mail of multiple commits in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-do-i-change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git)

Comment: See also [Is there a way to override a git author's display name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8878615/11343) for an alternative way to do this

Answer (score 3):

Did you reset the author on your commit after updating your details?

```
git commit --amend --reset-author
```

(This will bring up the commit message again - you can just leave it intact)

Comment: thanks, but when I use:git commit --amend --reset-author
I got: error: Terminal is dumb, but EDITOR unset
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

Comment: Sounds like you are using a regular cmd.exe shell instead of the msysgit bash

Comment: Try `git commit --amend --reset-author -m ""`