# How to override git author name in local settings?

Tags: git, git-svn

My git repository is imported from svn. And the username in `git log` is something like 0129. I want to override it with my setting like John instead of 0129. And I find this:

[Is there a way to override a git author's display name in local repository config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878615/is-there-a-way-to-override-a-git-authors-display-name-in-local-repository-confi)

The .mailmap solution works well in `git shortlog`, but `git log` still give the same output. Any suggestions?

*EDIT*
I've check [Change the author and committer name and e-mail of multiple commits in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-do-i-change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git/870367#870367) too but I don't want to run `git filter branch` every time after `git svn rebase`.

Comment: Perhaps you wanna rewrite all commits history like [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/870367/570689).

Comment: @ДМИТРИЙМАЛИКОВ Thanks, but I don't want to `git filter-branch` after every `git svn rebase`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the mapping of authors in the moment of migrating from svn to git, using git-svn:

```
  mkdir project_tmp
  cd project_tmp
  git-svn init https://company.project.org/project --no-metadata
  git config svn.authorsfile ~/Desktop/users.txt
  git-svn fetch
```

And the users.txt file is like this:

```
  xavier.fuster = xavier.fuster <xavier.fuster@project.org>
  francesc.dalmau = francesc.dalmau <francesc.dalmau@project.org>
```

The first part of the equal is the svn user name, the second part is the git name.

After this you need to do normal clone to leave all the svn stuff behind:

```
 git clone project_tmp project
```

Comment: Thanks @FerCa, is there anyway to avoid another `git clone` and use the svn.authorsfile now?

Answer (score 1):

have you had a look at the `--authors-file` when cloning/fetching/rebasing/...?

suppliying the authors-file, will allow you to use sane names. the syntax of the authors-file is something like the following, with 1 author per line:

```
svn_user_name = JustNameInGit <obligatory@email.com>
```